# What is the meaning of "behind" in "the engine behind 5G radio"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "behind" in the following sentences?

> Xilinx is ***the engine behind 5G radio*** and mMIMO deployment. Only
>   Xilinx provides adaptable 5G communication platforms, with highly
>   integrated silicon featuring RF ADC & DACs, accelerated 5G NR, and the
>   highest efficiency performance for mMIMO Radios, macro base station,
>   and small cell deployments.

(Soruce==> https://www.xilinx.com/applications/wireless-communications/wireless-connectivity.html)

Does "Xilinx is the engine **behind** 5G radio and mMIMO deployment" mean "Xilinx is the engine **in order to work** 5G radio and mMIMO deployment" ?

Does "behind" in the sentence mean "in order to work" or "for" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[American Heritage Dictionary "behind" (6)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=behind) 
In a position or attitude of support

[Merriam-Webster "behind" (4a)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/behind)
in support of : on the side of

[Collins Dictionary "behind" (6)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/behind)
6 If something or someone is behind you, they support you and help you.

So, the preposition "behind" means supporting. However, using the word "engine"  ("the engine behind 5G") tries to claim a central role for Xilinx equipment, as if it were essential. This advertising seems to claim that Xilinx is indispensible.

Comment: Dictionary.com has "originating, supporting, or promoting". I think the "originating" sense is most apropos here. It's also used in phrases like "the company behind Spaghetti-O's" or "the people behind Breaking Bad". I'm surprised 2 of the dictionaries you cited don't include this sense. (Collins has "The people, reason, or events behind a situation are the causes of it or are responsible for it.")

Comment: The dictionary.com definition would sure fit. The reason I didn't include that sense from Collins is that is seems to be a negative one, as in "who is behind the mischief".